# issues configuring nginx with node.js app

Tags: node.js, linux, nginx, dns, centos

Trying to get nginx to proxy my node.js app and use a domain with it. I'm going to have many domains mapped to the server so i'm using separate `.conf` files for each server block. The issue i'm having right now is that I can only seem to get the default nginx page to show up when i go to the domain. I'll try to explain the current setup as clearly as possible, and if you need any more information please let me know.

**nginx.conf changes**

I set the root path to where my apps files are, `root /var/www;` so for example, an app would be deployed to the folder `/var/www/example.com`.

**server block config**

I created a new file for the server block `/etc/nginx/conf.d/example_com.conf` which contains

```
server
{
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name example.com www.example.com;

location /var/www
{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3103;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}
}
```

please note that going to my http://myip:3103 renders the app as it should and the file `/etc/nginx/proxy_params` contains

```
proxy_buffers 16 32k;
    proxy_buffer_size 64k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma $http_authorization;
    proxy_connect_timeout 59s;
    proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
    proxy_no_cache $http_pragma $http_authorization;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_send_timeout 600;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding '';
    proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Proxy '';
    proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Original-Request $request_uri;
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong here? Do you need any more info? Please let me know! nginx is pretty new for me and i feel like i'm super close i'm just note understanding something. Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration provides requests processing like this:

- requests to http://[www.]example.com/var/www[*] will be proxy_passed to
  you app
- all other requests will be processed like static/direct
  requests in default nginx directory

If you haven't static files and all request has to processing by app, then you should fix your configuration like this:

```
location /
  {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3103;
     include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
  }
```

If you have static files that can be served by nginx, then you should to complicate you configuration a bit like [here](https://geekflare.com/nginx-static-files-node-js/) or [here](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2011/12/using-nginx-to-server-static-files-instead-of-node-js/).

[Here is](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) documentation for understanding how to nginx works.